# Too many web design aid framework - Is it wise to use frameworks? advantage or disavantage?

Tags: web-development, website-design, css-framework

Too many web design aid framework - IS it wise to use frameworks? advantage or disavantage?

I have seen many framework

like...

impress.js

960grid framework

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the big over complicated frameworks (cough, Microsoft), primarily because they can make it hard for a future developer to understand the code.  However, I do like jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is a great framework, and makes life soooo much easier in a lot of cases. That's the only framework I use in my projects.